# How to stop/close a NSLURLConnection during downloading

Tags: xcode, connection

```
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]];
        NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                initWithRequest:req
                                delegate:self
                                startImmediately:NO];
        [con scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                       forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [con start];

        if (con) {

            self.receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        } else {

            ...
        }   
        [req release];
```

With this code, I'm downloading an image.

How can I stop the downloading and close the connection during download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSURLConnection has a -cancel method.

Hope that helps!